# Firefox does not sort bookmarks automatically

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, sorting

Whenever I add a site to my bookmarks, Firefox puts it at the end of the list. In order to sort my bookmarks by name, I have to right click on the relevant folder and select "Sort by Name".

Is there a way to make Firefox sort the bookmarks by name as default so that I won't have to do the above thing each time I bookmark a page?

Answer (score 3):

I did not try it myself, but the [SortPlaces](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sortplaces/) addon should work.

<del>More information can be found [here](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/free-software-downloads/sort-firefox-bookmarks-by-name-or-by-folder-automatically/)</del>.

Comment: SortPlaces does not sort within the folders. The second link is corrupted.

Comment: "This add-on has been removed by its author."

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension to do this.  See:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Sorting_bookmarks_alphabetically#Using_an_extension_to_sort_bookmarks_recursively

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the author of "Sort Places", which is a Great extension, and Mozilla have had a falling out and he no longer makes it available.  If you already have it, it will continue to work.  That last version I saw was 1.92 and it works up through Firefox 14. If you downloaded the .xpi while it was available, you can still install it, but otherwise there's no longer any elegant way to sort Firefox bookmarks

Answer (score 0):

This addon works with Firefox 57 (webextensions):

https://addons.mozilla.org/ca/firefox/addon/sort-bookmarks-webext/

It's very spartan, very few options and you get your bookmarks sorted.